# How to overwrite child element style with ngStyle

Tags: css, angular

I need to set a style for entire div but it doesn't work for child components:

```
<div class=“myClass” [ngStyle]="{'cursor': 'not-allowed'}">
        <button class=“myButton”>
                OK
         </button>
 </div>
```

How can I do that? And same for this case:

```
<div class=“myClass” [ngStyle]="{'cursor': 'not-allowed'}">
        <button class=“myButton” [ngStyle]="{'cursor': 'default'}">
                OK
         </button>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**

In your first example, the problem is just that the browser's default CSS style for the button is more specific than your div's `not-allowed` cursor. If you want the `not-allowed` cursor to apply to both div and child elements, you can apply a `notAllowed` class to your div and have a rule like this

**component.css**

```
 .notAllowed, .notAllowed *
{
  cursor: not-allowed;
}
```

Now, if you want to be able to change the cursor dynamically, depending on some condition, just add the class dynamically by binding it to the condition variable

**component.html**

```
<div class="myClass" [class.notAllowed]="notAllowed ">
        <button class="myButton">
                OK
         </button>
 </div>
```

**component.ts**

```
public notAllowed = true;
```

I created a stackblitz for this

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5z9ru4?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

**Initial answer**

Why don't you set it in your css?

```
myClass, myClass>*{ cursor: not-allowed;}
```

Or using

```
  <div [style.cursor]="'not-allowed'"
```

Comment: it needs to be calculated like [ngStyle]="{'cursor' : myvar ? 'wait': 'default'}". So this is why I thought ngStyle would work